# Why is any finite set of points on a twisted cubic curve, in general position?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Please, how to show that any finite set of points on a twisted cubic curve $ \nu ( \mathbb{P}^1 ) $ with $ \nu : \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^3 $ defined by :
$$ \nu ( [X_0 : X_1 ] ) = [ X_0^3 : X_0^2 X_1 : X_0 X_1^2 : X_1^3 ] $$
in general position ( i.e : any four of them span $ \mathbb{P}^3 $ ) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, show that the twisted cubic is not planar.

The intersection of a hyperplane with a non-planar cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is a variety of dimension zero.  How many points can it have?

The answer follows from the general version of Bézout's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $p_1,\ldots,p_4$ be distinct points on the twisted cubic curve $\nu(\mathbb P^1)$. We need to show that the corresponding vectors of $p_i$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb K^4$. Suppose $$p_i=\nu([1:Y_i])=[1:Y_i:Y_i^2:Y_i^3].$$ Then consider the Vandermonde matrix
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & Y_1 & Y_1^2  & Y_1^{3}\\
1 & Y_2 & Y_2^2  & Y_2^{3}\\
1 & Y_3 & Y_3^2  & Y_3^{3}\\
1 & Y_4 & Y_4^2  & Y_4^3
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We have $\det V=\prod_{1 \le i < j \le 4} (Y_j - Y_i)\neq 0$. So the row vectors are independent.

To solve the general case, use the fact that $\nu(\mathbb P^1)=\{[1: a: a^2: a^3]\mid a\in\mathbb K\}\cup \{[0: 0: 0: 1]\}$.

Comment: Why can you take the first coordinate to be $1$ for every $p_i$? We know either the first or second coordinate is nonzero, so we can "normalize" things. But why can we WLOG assume the first coordinate is nonzero? Why couldn't the $1$'s be distributed on the first and last column?

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're doing; it seems that you are rescaling the rows and defining new variables, but I don't see why the resulting matrix has non-zero determinant. I looked at some special cases, but I couldn't see it.

Comment: Could you reduce it to this case somehow by conjugating by permutation matrices?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the determinant of $V$? If that is the case, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/699339/588038) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Proofs). If you are asking about the general case, I realised yesterday that it is also easy because the twisted cubic curve is the set $\{[1: a: a^2: a^3]\mid a\in\mathbb K\}\cup \{[0: 0: 0: 1]\}$. @user193319

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier way to see this when the twisted cubic is defined from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^3$.

If possible, let $P_i=(p_i,p_i^2,p_i^3)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ be four **distinct** points on the plane
$$Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$
Then, we have the four simultaneous equations
$$Ap_i+Bp_i^2+Cp_i^3+D=0$$
for $i=1,2,3,4$.

But, this simply means that the equation
$$AP+BP^2+CP^3+D=0$$
has four distinct solutions $p_i$, $i=1,2,3,4$.

This is a contradiction (since the last equation is a cubic).